# Do home routers typically ignore Static PAT for outbound traffic?

Tags: router

Port forwarding, aka Static PAT, allows a fixed translation between any outside source endpoint to a specific inside endpoint, for the public IP and a specific port .

However, if a packet is sent *from* that specific inside endpoint, on my router I see dynamic PAT employed and traffic established over an ephemeral port mapping.

Is this typical router behavior? If so what router options/config pages can be edited to change that,if any?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably seeing NAT (network address translation): A connection originating from the local network has its source address rewritten as the source address of the router. As there may be several outgoing connections, the source port is also rewritten so it can be mapped back to the (original source address, original destination address) pair.

Yes, this is default behaviour of many home routers, because usually your ISP only gives you a single IPv4 address, and all your home devices must share this address.

It totally depends on the UI of your brand of router how to disable this. Look for "NAT" or "Network address translation". Note that if you disable it, you'll have to talk your ISP to route several IP addresses to you, which in general costs quite a bit more.

This is completely different for port forwarding (or PAT, as you call it), where a destination port on the router is mapped to a specific device with a specific port in the local network. Also note that once such a connection is established, the actual connection may use different ports pairs, which again may undergo NAT.

**Edit**

The way port forwarding typically works is like this:

Assume you have a web server listening on port 8080 on an internal computer A. The router R forwards its own port 80 to 8080 on A.

Now some computer I somewhere on the internet sends a request to R on port 80. R rewrites that packet and sends it to A with port 8080. On receiving the connection request, A forks a new process, and establishes a connection with I using that port.

Now R should user proper connection tracking and recognize that I and A have established a connection. Which means the NAT will change the port according to the recognized connection, i.e. translate from 8080 to 80.

So the feature you want ("map an outgoing port to the same port that is forwarded while incoming") is not useful in this situation. What gets mapped is the **connection**.

If you need such a rule for some reason that even works without an established connection (I cannot imagine a reason why you should need it), then you can do that, but you'll need root access to router R (which may mean a custom firmware like OpenWRT), and you'll need to add `iptables` rules for that yourself.

The really interesting question is: What is your use case for mapping a port in the other direction? Why do you think you need to configure it?

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest if routers typically offer a method of reusing the static pat internal endpoint (endpoint = ip+port) for outbound traffic without disabling NAT. My understanding is that this is dynamic pat, i.e. Outbound traffic to an external endpoint will temporarily asdign a port for that external destination alone. I want dynamic pat to be abandoned when a port forward rule is in place, but on typical home routers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. You are using port forwarding to make a port on an internal machine accessible from the outside. This is a static affair: Either you run a server on your internal machine, or you don't. You can do other fancy stuff like load-balancing (forwarding the same port to different internal machines), but no off-the-shelf home router will offer a UI for that, you'll need to install OpenWRT etc. If you prefer the name "dynamic PAT" for NAT, then no, you can't disable "dynamic PAT" without disabling NAT.

Comment: If you are worried that the forwarded port will clash with the NAT: For privileged ports, this won't happen. I'm actually not sure how this is handled for unprivileged ports (home routers are nearly always embedded Linux machines, so you'd need to read up on the conntrack kernel module, and how it interacts with port-forwarding iptables rules).

Comment: Well, my understanding of 'port forwarding' is that that term is an alias for 'static pat', meaning that an ip/port combination on the inside is statically mapped to an ip/port combo on the outside. My understanding of that situation is that it should be bidirectional. Meaning if I initiate UDP traffic from the inside IP+port, it should be sent out from that IP+port externally mapped in the port forward table (napt table). Instead what I think I am seeing at least on my router is that that mapping is ignored for outbound traffic.

Comment: In fact, even with a fixed IP on the WAN, the outbound port is always dynamic on my router irrespective of the port forwarding rules, I think. Is this the norm, or can I usually configure this?